# javascript promise handling

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using [node-unifi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-unifi) and the basic structure looks structure of a request looks like:

```
const unifi = require('node-unifi');
const controller = new unifi.Controller({host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8443, sslverify: false});

controller.login('admin', 'PASSWORD')
  .then(result => {
    console.log('login: ' + result);
    return controller.createnetwork(payload);
  });
```

I'm trying to wrap the 'controller.createnetwork(payload)' call into a for loop. If I use a return statement, it dutifully breaks out of the loop upon the first run. If I remove the return, I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and only the last iteration of the loop actually gets submitted.

What's the proper method for calling a function like this in a loop while fulfilling the Promise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code. Please provide the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` syntax with `try/catch` to achieve synchronous behaviour

```js
const unifi = require('node-unifi');
const controller = new unifi.Controller({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8443,
    sslverify: false
});

controller.login('admin', 'PASSWORD')
    .then(async (result) => {
        console.log('login: ' + result);
        // replace empty array with the values you want to loop on
        for (const value of []) {
            try {
                const networkResp = await controller.createnetwork(payload);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`Error has occurred`);
                console.log(e);
        }
  }
});
```